# php preg_replace for all occurences of specific html tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm going to replace all `<pre><code>CONTENT</code></pre>` content .

```
<pre class="language-php"><code>m1
 </code></pre>
 lets go 
<pre class="language-php"><code>m2
</code></pre>
```

but running `preg_replace("/<pre(.*)<\/pre>/s", "SAMAN", $input_lines);` would output this:

```
SAMAN
```

while i need this output:

```
SAMAN lets go SAMAN
```

[here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jav) is my live test result

Answer (score 2):

`*` quantifier is greedy, append it with `?` to turn it into non-greedy. i.e. your regex should be: `/<pre(.*?)<\/pre>/s`

Answer (score 0):

The Code is:

```
<?php
$input_lines='<pre class="language-php"><code>m1
 </code></pre>
 lets go 
<pre class="language-php"><code>m2
</code></pre>';

$new_string=preg_replace("/(\r?\n?<pre.*?\/pre>\r?\n?)/s","SAMAN",$input_lines);
echo $new_string;
?>
```

Outputs:

```
SAMAN lets go SAMAN
```

Regex Pattern Explanation:

```
(                   # Begin capture group
    \r?\n?          # Optional newline characters on Windows and Linux
    <pre.*?\/pre>   # Match from opening pre tag to closing pre tag
    \r?\n?          # Optional newline characters on Windows and Linux
)                   # End capture group
/s                  # Force all dots in pattern to allow newline characters
```

My answer very closely resembles LeleDumbo's answer which probably performs to the asker's satisfaction.  I merely omitted the unnecessary `<` from the closing pre tag, and included some newline characters so that $new_string doesn't have any hidden characters in it (this may or may not be an issue depending on usage).